# Enforcing RemoteAttribute in MVC 3.0 when client side validation fails

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC object (3.0) that uses the `RemoteAttribute` to verify whether a name already exists in a database. This works fine, however in testing we are having instances where people clicking submit rapidly enough can get a form submission through before the validation finishes.

My first thought to this is to make sure that validation occurs on the server side, as well. Is there any way to enforce this without writing another custom validator attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to enforce validation on the server side because relying only on client side validation is not enough. So writing another custom validation attribute is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget if( ModelState.IsValid ) ... on the server side ?